# Почему на руСО нет метки "Inferno"/"acme"/"Limbo"?

Tags: обсуждение, метки

Если человек захочет задать вопрос, например,  "Как установить Inferno", но у него нет репы для создания метки -  что ему делать?

Comment: Может попросить создать на мете)

Comment: а что это такое?

Answer (score 4):

1. Потому что метка не может существовать без вопросов. И даже с одним вопросом она существует не так уж долго.
2. Потому что никому не надо.